# 2d linear Partial Differential Equation Solver using finite differences

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, scipy

This is code that solves partial differential equations on a rectangular domain using partial differences. `fd_solve` takes an equation, a partially filled in output, and a tuple of the x, y, and t steps to use. `eqn_parse` turns a representation of an equation to a lambda equation that can be easily used. in `__main__`, I have created two examples that use this code, one for the wave equation, and the other for the heat equation. Running this code requires `numpy`, `scipy`, and `plotly`.

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np

def fd_solve(eqn, zs, boundary):
    # Coordinates for evaluating.
    xs, ys, ts = boundary

    offset = np.any(zs[1, -1:1, -1:1]) # 1 if u_tt != 0
    # Loop through time
    for i, t in enumerate(ts[:-1], start=offset):
        zs[i+1, 1:-1,1:-1] = eqn(zs, i)

    # Magic to make it plot
    nframe = 100
    frames = [{'name': str(t), 'data': [{'z': zs[i], 'type':'surface'}]} for i,t in enumerate(ts) if i % nframe == 0]
    steps = [{'method': 'animate', 'label': str(t)[0:5],
                          'args': [[str(t)], {'frame': {'duration': 100}, 'mode': 'immediate'}]} for t in ts if t % nframe == 0]
    print(len(frames))
    figure = {'data': [go.Surface(x=xs, y=ys, z=zs[0])],
              'layout': {},
              'frames': frames}
    figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [{
                'buttons': [{'args': [None,
                                     {'frame': {'duration': 500},
                                      'fromcurrent': True,
                                      'transition': {'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                                    'label': 'Play',
                                    'method': 'animate'},
                            {'args': [[None],
                                      {'frame': {'duration': 0,},
                                       'mode': 'immediate',
                                       'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                                    'label': 'Pause',
                                    'method': 'animate'}],
                'type': 'buttons', 'x': 0.1, 'y': .05}]
    sliders_dict = {'active': 0,
                    'currentvalue': {'font': {'size': 20}, 'prefix': 't: ',
                                     'xanchor': 'right'},
                    'transition': {'duration': 100},
                    'steps': steps}
    figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]
    plot(figure)

def eqn_parse(dt=.01, dx=.05, ts=(0,1,0), xs=(0,0,1), ys=(0,0,1)):
    ''' Numerical kernel for PDEs of the form
        ts[1]*u_t + ts[2]*u_tt = xs[1]*u_x + xs[2]*u_xx + ys[1]*u_y + ys[2]'''

    assert xs[0]==ys[0]==0

    # 2nd deriv
    kernel = np.array([[0,        ys[2],         0],
                       [xs[2], -2*ys[2]-2*xs[2], xs[2]],
                       [0,        ys[2],         0]])
    kernel /= dx

    # 1st deriv
    kernel += .5 * np.array([[0,    -ys[1], 0],
                            [-xs[1], 0,     xs[1]],
                            [ 0,     ys[1], 0]])
    kernel /= dx

    if ts[0]==ts[2]==0:
        kernel *= dt * ts[1]
        return lambda zs, i, : zs[i, 1:-1,1:-1] + convolve2d(zs[i], kernel, mode='valid')

    if ts[0]==ts[1]==0:
        kernel *= dt*dt*ts[2]
        return lambda zs, i, : (-zs[i-1, 1:-1,1:-1]
                               + 2 * zs[i, 1:-1,1:-1]
                               + convolve2d(zs[i], kernel, mode='valid'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    # Wave eqn
    dx,c =.01,.5
    dt = dx/(10*c) # dt < dx/(c) for stability
    eqn = eqn_parse(dt=dt, dx=dx, ts=(0,0,1), xs=(0,0,c), ys=(0,0,c))

    xs, ys, ts = np.arange(-1,1,dx), np.arange(-1,1,dx), np.arange(0,10,dt)

    # Boundary conditions
    bc = lambda t, x, y : (x-x+y-y)*(t-t) #(x**2-y**3)*np.cos(t)
    zs = bc(ts[:,None,None],xs[None,:,None], ys[None,None,:])

    # Initial Conditions
    zs[0, 1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
    zs[0, 1:-1, 1:-1] = dt*np.exp(-(xs[1:-1, None]**2+ys[None, 1:-1]**2)**.5)
    zs[2:, 1:-1, 1:-1] = 0

    fd_solve(eqn, zs, (xs,ys,ts))
    '''
    # Heat eqn
    dx,k =.05,1.0
    dt = dx*dx/(16*k) # dt < dx*dx/(4*k) for stability

    eqn = eqn_parse(dt=dt, dx=dx, ts=(0,k,0), xs=(0,0,k), ys=(0,0,k))
    xs, ys, ts = np.arange(-1,1,dx), np.arange(-1,1,dx), np.arange(0,2,dt)

    # Boundary conditions
    bc = lambda t, x, y : (x**2+y**2)*np.cos(3*t)
    zs = bc(ts[:,None,None], xs[None,:,None], ys[None,None,:])

    # Initial Conditions
    ic = lambda t, x, y : (t-t)+1
    zs[0,1:-1,1:-1] = ic(ts[:1,None,None],xs[None,1:-1,None], ys[None,None,1:-1])
    zs[1:,1:-1,1:-1] = 0

    fd_solve(eqn, zs, (xs,ys,ts))
    ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no docstring for `fd_solve`. The post contains a description that would make a good start.
2. The docstring has `zs[2:, 1:-1, 1:-1] = 0` but this doesn't match the code `zs[1:,1:-1,1:-1] = 0`.
3. `eqn_parse` does not seem to parse anything. I think you could pick a better name, for example `pde_kernel`.
4. `eqn_parse` might return `None` in some circumstances. Is this the expected behaviour? It would be better to raise an exception if the input is incorrect.
5. When building a dictionary, it is often clearer to call `dict` instead of using a dictionary literal. When calling `dict` you don't have to quote the keys, which reduces the amount of syntactic clutter. For example:

   ```
   sliders_dict = dict(active=0,
                       currentvalue=dict(font=dict(size=20),
                                         prefix='t: ',
                                         xanchor='right'),
                       steps=steps,
                       transition=dict(duration=100))
   ```
6. Instead of:

   ```
   ts[:,None,None], xs[None,:,None], ys[None,None,:]
   ```

   I suggest using [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to make it clear that you are constructing a grid of coordinates:

   ```
   np.meshgrid(ts, xs, ys, sparse=True, indexing='ij')
   ```
7. Instead of `(t-t)+1`, I suggest using `np.ones_like(t)` to make it clear that you are constructing an array of ones with the same shape and dtype as `t`. (See [`numpy.ones_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html).) But since this is constant, why not just write `zs[0,1:-1,1:-1] = 1` and avoid the need for `ic`?
8. The slice `1:-1` appears in many places; I suggest making a global constant, for example `INTERIOR = slice(1, -1)`.
9. The boundary condition computation is wasteful as most of the values computed will be overwritten in the subsequent steps. It might be better to start with

   ```
   zs = np.zeros(ts.shape + xs.shape + ys.shape)
   ```

   and then fill in the values only in the boundary planes:

   ```
   BOUNDARY = [0, -1]
   INTERIOR = slice(1, -1)
   zs[0, INTERIOR, INTERIOR] = 1
   zs[:, BOUNDARY, :] = bc(*np.meshgrid(ts, xs[BOUNDARY], ys, sparse=True, indexing='ij'))
   zs[:, INTERIOR, BOUNDARY] = bc(*np.meshgrid(ts, xs[INTERIOR], ys[BOUNDARY], sparse=True, indexing='ij'))
   ```

   (The repetition in the last two lines can easily be eliminated using a helper function.)